# How to use a script to generate a Trac Milestone complete with a description?

Tags: python, trac

The description is the body of a milestone, and I'd like to generate milestones that include descriptions in an automated process.

Trac doesn't behave well if you directly update the tables in its database, so even though I can see the milestones there, I would avoid taking that approach.

Using the `trac-admin` command line utility documented at https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/0.11/TracAdmin almost does the trick, as it allows milestones to be created, but it stops short of being able to specify a description for a milestone.

The `MilestoneModule` and `RoadmapModule` classes here: https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/trac/api/trac_ticket_roadmap.html look promising but `MilestoneModule` and `RoadmapModule` don't seem to offer the ability to create and list milestones.

So there must be some mostly undocumented class or method for doing this. What is it?

Comment: [XmlRpcPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin) has an API for creating milestones.

Comment: To answer the question you posed in your deleted post about virtualbox: it is just as off-topic as the one you dug up; but there are too many question dashing past to catch all the off-topic ones all the time.  Thanks for pointing out the other one - it has also been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add milestones using the MilestoneCache object, like this script does  (or just use the script, which is what I do either from the command line or from Python3 via subprocess.run, since Trac currently runs on Python2 and not 3)

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from trac.env import open_environment
from trac.ticket import Milestone
from trac.ticket.model import MilestoneCache
from trac.core import TracError
import sys, json;

if len(sys.argv)!=2:
  print '''
  Usage: python2 createMilestone.py2 dir

  e.g.   python2 createMilestone.py2 ~/trac M3 <<END
         { "name": "M3",
           "due": "2021-01-01 04:00:00+00:00",
           "completed": "2021-12-31 23:59:59+00:00",
           "description": "" }
         END
  '''
  exit(3)

try:
  data = json.load(sys.stdin)
except:
  sys.stderr.write("Bad input data")
  exit(2)

try:
  mc=MilestoneCache(open_environment(sys.argv[1]))
  mc.factory((data['name'],data['due'],data['completed'],data['description'])).insert()  
except:
  sys.stderr.write("Can't update "+sys.argv[1]+"\n")
  exit(1)
```

The script takes JSON with all the fields of the milestone as input. It's the same technique I use for creating tickets when writing Python3, since Trac is a Python2 program.

Conversely, if you want to list milestones, you can use this similar script, and you can pipe a milestone listed as jSON from one Trac site to another.

Sometimes I teach courses where I prepare a Trac site for each student, and I dump milestones through this script below and pipe it through the script above to propagate it into student Trac sites.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from trac.env import open_environment
from trac.ticket import Milestone
from trac.ticket.model import MilestoneCache
from trac.core import TracError
import sys, json;

if len(sys.argv)!=3:
  print '''
  Usage: python2 getMilestone dir milestone

  e.g.   python2 getMilestone ~/trac M3
  '''
  exit(3)

try:
  name,due,completed,description = MilestoneCache(open_environment(sys.argv[1])).milestones[sys.argv[2]]
  print json.dumps({
    "name":name,
    "due":str(due) if due else None,
    "completed":str(completed) if completed else None,
    "description":description
  },indent=2)
except KeyError:
  pass
except TracError:
  sys.stderr.write("Can't open "+sys.argv[1]+"\n")
  exit(1)
```